# List all the views created in the design doc

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

Can couchdb list all the views created in the design doc?  If so what is the query?  Futon does it somehow, but I can't seem to figure it out from there code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just retrieve design document you like and enumerate all keys of `views` field. Futon works in a little other way since it [shows all views](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/share/www/database.html#L91) from [all design documents](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/share/www/script/futon.browse.js#L404), but principle is the same. Note, that design documents are not some sort of magic - they are same documents as others, just have some internal agreements with CouchDB about fields structure and processing workflow.